# Showing different colours for UIButtons on press within IBAction for a Quiz

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, if-statement, uibutton

I have four `UIButtons` that represent 4 answers. I've managed to get everything hooked up and showing the correct answer in green and the wrong answer in Red.

My only problem is when a user selects a wrong answer I grey out all the answers. I want to show the user the correct answer as well. I've tried else if statements but am missing something, any suggestions?

```
-(IBAction)Answer1:(id)sender{

    if (Answer1Correct == YES) {
        [Answer1 setTitle:@"Correct" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        [self RightAnswer];
    }
    else{

        [Answer1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [Answer1 setTitle:@"Incorrect" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:102.0/255.0 green:102.0/255.0 blue:102.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f]];
        [Answer3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:102.0/255.0 green:102.0/255.0 blue:102.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f]];
        [Answer4 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:102.0/255.0 green:102.0/255.0 blue:102.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f]];
        [self WrongAnswer];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you writing separate code for each button??

Comment: and you are storing 4 boolean values `Answer-x-correct` to know which is right answer, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm writing separate code for each button @ShahiM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 if (Answer1Correct == YES) {
    [Answer1 setTitle:@"Correct" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [Answer1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [self RightAnswer];
}
else{

    [Answer1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [Answer2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greyColor]];
    [Answer3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greyColor]];
    [Answer4 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greyColor]];

    if(Answer2isCorrect)
      { [Answer2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]]; }
    else if(Answer3isCorrect)
      { [Answer3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]]; }
    else if(Answer4isCorrect)
      { [Answer4 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]]; }
}
```

if selected answer is wrong, first set all other buttons to grey, then find the correct answer and change that to green.

you may also want to disable the all buttons once an answer is clicked to prevent further clicks.

Comment: Hi ShahiM - Thanks for this but this only shows green for the correct answer and grey for the incorrect one. If you read the question again it says Red for incorrect, Green for Correct, Grey if not clicked...

Comment: Absolutely spot on thank you ShahiM!! Marked as Correct.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is inherit from `UIButton`. Create class `QuizQuestionButton`
This Class will have method 
`-setCorrectAnswer:(NSString *)correctAnswer` and `-setRealAnswer:(NSString *)realAnswer`

If this both is same - set background color as Green, else as Red.

```
-(void)setCorrectAnswer:(NSString *)correctAnswer {
     _correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
}

-(void)setRealAnswer:(NSString *)realAnswer {
    if (realAnswer == _correctAnswer) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    } else {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
}
```

Also read about design pattern - Strategy. This pattern can help you avoid if-else statement.

Comment: Thanks Pavel but this doesn't answer my question about grey-ing out the remaining buttons...

Comment: @user4625544 You can modify this to your requirements. But this is the best approach.